# How to find sum of series Σ 1/ ((2n - 1)^2 (2n+1)^2)

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find sum of the series Σ 1/ ((2n - 1)^2 (2n+1)^2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica gives the answer 
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2 n-1)^2 (2 n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2-8}{16}.$$
An elementary way to prove this is to write 
$$\frac{4}{(2 n-1)^2 (2 n+1)^2}=
\frac{1}{2 n+1}-\frac{1}{2 n-1}+\frac{1}{(2 n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}  
$$
and then 
\begin{equation}
 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\Big(\frac{1}{2 n+1}-\frac{1}{2 n-1}\Big)=-\frac{1}{2\times1-1}=-1
\end{equation}
by telescoping, 
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2 n-1)^2}=\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{m^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2 n)^2}
=\frac34\,\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{m^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8},
$$
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}=-1+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2 k-1)^2}=-1+\frac{\pi^2}{8}.
$$

Comment: Could you provide more details how do you figure out this?

Comment: @Subuday: Does the expression "partial fraction decomposition" ring a bell?

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. : It did. :-)